# Can you make persistent global variables in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I learned a little while ago that background threads can't be trusted in asp.net due to the nature of IIS, they can be wiped from existence any second.

Question is, is the same true for global variables that I declare inside class as a shared field for example? I don't know how to test for that since I've yet to witness the disappearing thread but figured that if one can happen, so could the other.

As a more specific example, lets say I have this class:

```
Public Class DataHolder
    Public Shared data1 As String
    Public Shared data2 As String

    Shared Sub New()
        Dim fdat = IO.File.ReadAllLines(System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath & "localcache.txt")
        data1 = fdat(0)
        data2 = fdat(1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

2 things that I expect from this class:

1. That the data1 and data2 always correspond to the values provided by localcache.txt (they won't be modified by the code)
2. That data1 and data2 are actually fetched from memory and no trickery such as running the constructor every time I use either of those values are used to compensate for no real global memory

Can this class meet those standards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS is primarily a request based system. It tends to shutdown everything if there is no activity (i.e. no sessions in progress).

The shared constructor will be called whenever instantiating the class for first time. So, what you are doing will work consistently as long as you don't modify those shared variables outside the shared constructor.